# Python printing & (and) character in MS word through python

Tags: python, dataframe, ms-word, docxtpl

I am generating MS word files through Python using `docxtpl`. I am trying to import the `Humanities&Social Sciences` text into an MS word file. But, I see `Humanities Sciences` printed in MS word.

I tried these combinations, but they did not work: `Humanities&&Social Sciences`, `Humanities\&Social Sciences`. What should I write in python so that when I import it into MS word, I see the full and complete text?

Answer (score 1):

How Escaping works in [docxtpl](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is given below. Following this will solve your issue.

By default, no escaping is done.

When you use a {{  }}, under the hood, you are modifying an XML word document, this means you cannot use all chars, especially <, > and &. In order to use them, you must escape them. There are 4 ways :

```
    context = { 'var':R('my text') } and {{r <var> }} in the template (note the r),
    context = { 'var':'my text'} and {{ <var>|e }} in your word template
    context = { 'var':escape('my text')} and {{ <var> }} in the template.
    enable autoescaping when calling render method: tpl.render(context, autoescape=True) (default is autoescape=False)
```

See tests/escape.py example for more informations.

Another solution, if you want to include a listing into your document, that is to escape the text and manage \n, \a, and \f you can use the Listing class

in your python code:

```
context = { 'mylisting':Listing('the listing\nwith\nsome\nlines \a and some paragraph \a and special chars : <>&') }
```

in your docx template just use **{{ mylisting }}**

With Listing(), you will keep the current character styling (except after a \a as you start a new paragraph).